# How do I make a plot using ggplot (R studio) in which items are separated by a categorising column?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-grid

From a matrix similar to the following (but quite a bit larger), saved as 'vb' in my Environment:

```
Food    Counts  se  Category
Apple   3   1   Fruit
Cauliflower 4   0.5 Vegetable
Banana  1   3   Fruit
Pear    7   3.2 Fruit
Broccoli    4   1.4 Vegetable
Brussel's sprouts   7   7   Vegetable
```

I'd like to make a plot displaying the counts + standard errors of the different foods, organised by 'category' (i.e., fruits and vegetables clumped together in different plots). I've used to following code in R:

```
ggplot(vb, aes(y=Counts, x=Food)) + 
  geom_point(color="#104E8B") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Counts-2*se, ymax=Counts+2*se), width=.2,color="#104E8B") +
  facet_grid(Category ~ ., scales = "free", space = "free_y") +
  ylim(0, 10) +
  coord_flip()
```

However, this will still list the fruits alongside the vegetables and vice versa. It only omits the data points from foods belonging to the other category,
[see picture for reference.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DV8Kh.png)

How do I get the 'Fruit' plot to only list fruits and the 'Vegetable' plot to only list vegetables?

**Data in dput format.**

```
vb <-
structure(list(Food = c("Apple", "Cauliflower", "Banana", 
"Pear", "Broccoli", "Brussel's sprouts"), Counts = c(3L, 
4L, 1L, 7L, 4L, 7L), se = c(1, 0.5, 3, 3.2, 1.4, 7), 
Category = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), 
.Label = c("Fruit", "Vegetable"), class = "factor")), 
row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Add reproducible data, try adding dput(head(vb)) to the question.

Comment: @HectorHaffenden Done.

Comment: Thanks! And sorry, I'm quite new here.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your graph, `facet_grid` lists only the vegetables in the lower panel and the fruits in the other.

Comment: It comes out just fine on my distro -  I get the fruits and vegetables separated on the facets.

Comment: Turns out, something was wrong with the installation of R on my macbook. Thank you so much for your time, though! It did really help knowing that, at least, the script was okay, so that I could look for problems elsewhere.